# How can I convert patterns into all of their possible combinations

Tags: php, php-5.6

I'm trying to convert numbers that are using variables into all of their possible results. Below are a few examples using US telephone numbers (sample numbers):

> 203618723[149] 7049164XXX 651280477[5-9] 203618717[01-7]
>   20361872[149]X

The output should be an array like:

```
2036187231 2036187234 2036187239 7049164000 7049164001 7049164002 .. 7049164010 7049164011 .. 7049164100 7047167101 .. 6512804775 6512804776 6512804777 6512804778 6512804779 2036187170 2036187171 2036187172 2036187273 .. 2036187210 2036187211 2036187212 .. 2036187240 2036187241 2036187242 .. 2036187290 2036187291 ..
```

What I have so far handles the last digit being a variable but fails with anything before that being one and doesn't handle ranges, I've been beating my head against the wall on this, any pointers or assistance would be appreciated.

```
echo "<pre>";
        print_r(str_split((string)$extended['168']['pattern']));
        echo "</pre>";

        $string = str_split((string)$extended['9200']['pattern']);
        $newnumber['168'] = array();
        $c = 0;
        $append = 0;
        foreach($string as $number) {
            if($number == "[") {
                $append = 1;
                $c2 = 0;
                continue;
            } elseif ($number == "]") {
                $append = 0;
                unset($c2);
                continue;
            } elseif ($number == "X") {
                $newnumber['168'][$c]['0'] = 0;
                $newnumber['168'][$c]['1'] = 1;
                $newnumber['168'][$c]['2'] = 2;
                $newnumber['168'][$c]['3'] = 3;
                $newnumber['168'][$c]['4'] = 4;
                $newnumber['168'][$c]['5'] = 5;
                $newnumber['168'][$c]['6'] = 6;
                $newnumber['168'][$c]['7'] = 7;
                $newnumber['168'][$c]['8'] = 8;
                $newnumber['168'][$c]['9'] = 9;
            } else  {
                if($append == 1) {
                    if($number == "-") {

                    } else {
                        $newnumber['168'][$c][$c2] = $number;
                        $c2++;
                        continue;
                    }
                } else {
                    $newnumber['168'][$c] = $number;
                }
            }
            $c++;
        }
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($newnumber['168']);
        echo "</pre>";



        /*foreach ($newnumber['168'] as $num) {
            if(is_array($num)) {
                foreach ($num as $num1) {
                    $numbers[] = $numstart . $num1;
                }
            } else {
                $numstart .= $num;
            }
        }*/
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($numbers);
        echo "</pre>";
```

My output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 6
    [4] => 1
    [5] => 8
    [6] => 7
    [7] => 2
    [8] => 3
    [9] => [
    [10] => 1
    [11] => 4
    [12] => 9
    [13] => ]
)
Array
(
    [0] => 7
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 9
    [4] => 1
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 4
    [7] => 9
    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 3
            [4] => 4
            [5] => 5
            [6] => 6
            [7] => 7
            [8] => 8
            [9] => 9
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 3
            [4] => 4
            [5] => 5
            [6] => 6
            [7] => 7
            [8] => 8
            [9] => 9
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => 704916490
    [1] => 704916491
    [2] => 704916492
    [3] => 704916493
    [4] => 704916494
    [5] => 704916495
    [6] => 704916496
    [7] => 704916497
    [8] => 704916498
    [9] => 704916499
    [10] => 704916490
    [11] => 704916491
    [12] => 704916492
    [13] => 704916493
    [14] => 704916494
    [15] => 704916495
    [16] => 704916496
    [17] => 704916497
    [18] => 704916498
    [19] => 704916499
)
```

Comment: If you are still using PHP5.3 then I strongly encourage you to upgrade. This version of PHP has not been supported for many years.

Comment: @Dan - no not at all

Answer (score 0):

Okay so this is probably NOT the cleanest way to do this but just in case anybody needs to do anything similar in the future:

This only works for 10 digit numbers and I haven't built in any error handling yet but that cleanup will start now.

```
$string = str_split((string)$value['pattern']);
                $newnumber[$key] = array();
                $c = 0;
                $append = 0;
                foreach($string as $number) {
                    if($number == "[") {
                        $append = 1;
                        $c2 = 0;
                        continue;
                    } elseif ($number == "]") {
                        $append = 0;
                        unset($c2);
                        continue;
                    } elseif ($number == ".") {
                        continue;
                    } elseif ($number == "X") {
                        $newnumber[$key][$c]['0'] = 0;
                        $newnumber[$key][$c]['1'] = 1;
                        $newnumber[$key][$c]['2'] = 2;
                        $newnumber[$key][$c]['3'] = 3;
                        $newnumber[$key][$c]['4'] = 4;
                        $newnumber[$key][$c]['5'] = 5;
                        $newnumber[$key][$c]['6'] = 6;
                        $newnumber[$key][$c]['7'] = 7;
                        $newnumber[$key][$c]['8'] = 8;
                        $newnumber[$key][$c]['9'] = 9;
                    } else  {
                        if($append == 1) {
                            if($number == "-") {
                                $dash = 1; 
                                continue;
                            } elseif ($dash == 1) {
                                $s = $newnumber[$key][$c][$c2-1];
                                for ($s = $s+1; $s <= $number; $s++) {
                                    $newnumber[$key][$c][$c2] = $s;
                                    $c2++;
                                }
                                unset($s);
                                unset($dash);
                            } else {
                                $newnumber[$key][$c][$c2] = $number;
                                $c2++;
                                continue;
                            }
                        } else {
                            $newnumber[$key][$c][] = $number;
                        }
                    }
                    $c++;
                }
                /*echo "<pre>";
                print_r($newnumber[$key]);
                echo "</pre>";*/

                $numbers = array();
                //Process first digit
                $d1 = 0;
                $n1arr = array();
                foreach ($newnumber[$key][0] as $digit1) {
                    $n1arr[$d1] .= $digit1;
                    $d1++;
                }

                $d2 = 0;
                $n2arr = array();
                foreach ($newnumber[$key][1] as $digit2) {
                    foreach ($n1arr as $n1n) {
                        $n2arr[$d2] = $n1n . $digit2;
                        $d2++;
                    }
                }

                $d3 = 0;
                $n3arr = array();
                foreach ($newnumber[$key][2] as $digit3) {
                    foreach ($n2arr as $n2n) {
                        $n3arr[$d3] = $n2n . $digit3;
                        $d3++;
                    }
                }

                $d4 = 0;
                $n4arr = array();
                foreach ($newnumber[$key][3] as $digit4) {
                    foreach ($n3arr as $n3n) {
                        $n4arr[$d4] = $n3n . $digit4;
                        $d4++;
                    }
                }

                $d5 = 0;
                $n5arr = array();
                foreach ($newnumber[$key][4] as $digit5) {
                    foreach ($n4arr as $n4n) {
                        $n5arr[$d5] = $n4n . $digit5;
                        $d5++;
                    }
                }

                $d6 = 0;
                $n6arr = array();
                foreach ($newnumber[$key][5] as $digit6) {
                    foreach ($n5arr as $n5n) {
                        $n6arr[$d6] = $n5n . $digit6;
                        $d6++;
                    }
                }

                $d7 = 0;
                $n7arr = array();
                foreach ($newnumber[$key][6] as $digit7) {
                    foreach ($n6arr as $n6n) {
                        $n7arr[$d7] = $n6n . $digit7;
                        $d7++;
                    }
                }

                $d8 = 0;
                $n8arr = array();
                foreach ($newnumber[$key][7] as $digit8) {
                    foreach ($n7arr as $n7n) {
                        $n8arr[$d8] = $n7n . $digit8;
                        $d8++;
                    }
                }

                $d9 = 0;
                $n9arr = array();
                foreach ($newnumber[$key][8] as $digit9) {
                    foreach ($n8arr as $n8n) {
                        $n9arr[$d9] = $n8n . $digit9;
                        $d9++;
                    }
                }

                $d10 = 0;
                $n10arr = array();
                foreach ($newnumber[$key][9] as $digit10) {
                    foreach ($n9arr as $n9n) {
                        $n10arr[$d10]['pattern'] = $n9n . $digit10;
                        $n10arr[$d10]['description'] = $extended[$key]['description'];
                        $n10arr[$d10]['translation'] = $extended[$key]['translation'];
                        $n10arr[$d10]['prefix'] = $extended[$key]['prefix'];
                        $d10++;
                    }
                }
```